# jquery how can I get data from html table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table:

```
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="product">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th colspan="2">Nr products</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($productsInStock as $product) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product->getCategory(); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product->getPrice().ProductController::coin; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product->getNrProducts(); ?></td>
                <td><button type="submit" value="Delete" class="upload" onclick="deleteDataTable();">Delete</button></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfieldname" class="hidden" value="<?php echo $product->getId();?>">
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

I need the value for every hidden field but I only get the first :

```
x = ('.hidden').val() // gives the first value
```

How can I get the different values after every click on delete button

Comment: Show your `deleteDataTable` method.

Comment: `<input>` is invalid child of `<tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is pass the ID as parameter to `deleteDataTable()` function.

```
<td><button type="submit" value="Delete" class="upload" onclick="deleteDataTable(<?php echo $product->getId();?>);">Delete</button></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: Context.

When you use

```
x = $('.hidden')
```

you get *all* elements with class 'hidden'.   `.val()` then gets the value from the first.

You need to limit the hidden input to the one on the same row as the delete button.

Unfortunately, your current hidden is not actually inside the table and you have this:

```
<table><tr>...</tr><tr>..</tr>
<input type="hidden"...>
<input type="hidden"...>
```

You need to change your markup to:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product->getCategory(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product->getPrice().ProductController::coin; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product->getNrProducts(); ?></td>
    <td>
        <button type="submit" value="Delete" class="upload" onclick="deleteDataTable();">Delete</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfieldname" class="hidden" value="<?php echo $product->getId();?>">
    </td>
</tr>
```

or similar so that the input is *inside* a `td`.

You can then use relative elements on the delete click:

```
function deleteDataTable()
{
    var x = $(this).closest("tr").find(".hidden").val();
}
```

or, using the amended html above, use `.next` but I would keep the above

```
    var x = $(this).next(".hidden").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
var x=[];
$('.hidden').each(function(){
    x.push($(this).val());
});
```

x should contain all the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can like that

```
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="product">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th colspan="2">Nr products</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($productsInStock as $product) : ?>
        <tr data-productid="<?php echo $product->getId();?>">
            <td><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product->getCategory(); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product->getPrice().ProductController::coin; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product->getNrProducts(); ?></td>
            <td><button type="submit" value="Delete" class="upload" onclick="deleteDataTable();">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Script

```
function deleteDataTable()
{
    var productIdOfCurrentTR = $(this).closest("tr").data("productid");
}
```

Comment: You'll need to add how to get the `data-productid` from the `tr` in the event handler.  This currently just explains how to put it somewhere else and would have the same problem given this code `var x = $("tr").data("productid")` which is the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product->getCategory(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product->getPrice().ProductController::coin; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product->getNrProducts(); ?></td>
    <td>
        <button type="submit" value="Delete" class="upload getValue" data-product-id="<?php echo $product->getId();?>">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>

<script>
$('.getValue').click(function(){
    var val = $(this).data('product-id');
});
</script>
```